# Making Facebook login with new Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, facebook-login

I want to implement Facebook login with new Firebase and I just can't get it right.

I added cocoapods, went through docs for both Firebase and Facebook. When I open my Simulator I get this: http://d.pr/i/bVPZ/4IBJKx9T

This is my ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    let loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Optional: Place the button in the center of your view.
        loginButton.center = self.view.center
        loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
        loginButton.delegate = self
        view!.addSubview(loginButton)
    }

    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError?) {
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        print("User logged in")
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        print("User logged out")
    }

    func loginButtonWillLogin(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) -> Bool {
        print("User will login")
        return true
    }
}
```

This is my AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FBSDKLoginKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        FIRApp.configure()
        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        return true
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        let handled: Bool = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
        return handled
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

Comment: Is any of `FBSDKLoginButton`'s delegate methods are called? If so, which one? What do you see in debug console?

Comment: I get this: 2016-05-28 17:25:31.564 fb-login[2189:20888] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"
2016-05-28 17:25:31.574 fb-login[2189:20888] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"

Comment: What delegate method is called, then?

Comment: didFinishWithError is called when I get back from that "you're not logged in" part.

Answer (score 1):

Add this as an else to your loginButton:didCompleteWithResult method. It completes the login on the Firebase side. Although, it wouldn't explain your current error.

```
let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)
FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential, completion: { (user, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    } else {
        self.signedIn(user)
    }
})
```

As for the current error, did you add the url schemes, app id, and app name that facebook provides in the developer console when you create an app to your info.plist? Seems to me that that is where it is failing. Your app needs to have permission from facebook to login.

Comment: I have everything docs say, including app id, name etc. in my plist.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work.

This was the problem:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }
```